# How to export RGB data in UIImage?

Tags: ios, uiimage, rgb

I want to get byte (UInt8) array in UIImage.

I think array size is width * height * 3 (because of R,G,B information) but most of this topic is using RGBA(not a RGB) so multiply 4.

This is my question.

1. What is difference between RGB and RGBA?
2. I just want to make a RGB data (not a RGBA) because I have to send 
   data which size is width * height * 3 (R,G,B) to server.
3. Do you have any idea that export R,G,B data (0~255) in each pixel?

Comment: RGBA & RGB both are same, here A stands for alpha of img.